# Vector spaces and bases proof verification

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I would like to know if my proof is correct and, moreover, if it is well formulated.

> Let $B = \{b_1 , \dots,b_n \}$ be a base of a vector space $E$. Prove that every vector of $E$
>               can be expressed only as a linear combination of the elements of $B$.

Let $u \in E$. $B$ is a base of $E$ $\implies E= \langle b_1, \dots, b_n \rangle \implies \exists \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb K $ such that
$$u = \alpha_1 b_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n b_n\qquad(1)$$

We have proved that the linear combination ***exists***. Now we will prove that this is unique.

Suppose that $\exists \lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb K$ such that
        $$u = \lambda_1 b_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n b_n\qquad(2)$$
        Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$:
        $$(\alpha_1 - \lambda_1) b_1 + \cdots + (\alpha_n - \lambda_n) b_n = 0_E$$
        But, as $B$ is a base and, $\forall i\; (\alpha_i - \lambda_i \in \mathbb K)$, the only solution of this equation is $\forall i\; (\alpha_i - \lambda_i = 0) \implies$ $\forall i\;(\alpha_i = \lambda_i) \implies$ the linear combination is ***unique***.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I think in the yellow parraph it should better be : "Prove that every vector of $\;E\;$ can be expressed **in a unique way** as a linear combination of the elements of $\;B\;$ " .